# What is causing I.E. to not validate (jquery) when other browsers do

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, validation, cross-browser

I have a form using jQuery 1.7 and jQuery validation 1.9 (latest each at the time of this post), which works on firefox / chrome / safari, but only partly works on I.E. (8.0 at least, haven't tested other versions) -- not sure what the deal is.
There's an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/bulbous/hZn5A/100/

if you click Test, you see that the text input control is validated in all browsers, but the dropdown isn't validated in i.e. (but is in all the others).
I'm including the full html for the example below also:

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.validate-1.9.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value, element, param) {
      return this.optional(element) || value != param;
  }, "Please choose some value!");

  $('#myForm').validate({
      rules: {
          text: {
              required: true
          },
          category: {
              required: true,
              notEqual: "---"
          }
      },
      messages: {
          text: {
              required: "Text required"
          },
          category: {
              required: "Category required"
          }
      }
  });
});
    </script>
<form id="myForm">
    <select id="category" name="category">
        <option>---</option>
        <option>Category 1</option>
        <option>Category 2</option>
        <option>Category 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="text" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Test" />
</form
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me in IE9. (Clicking "Test" shows "Please choose some value!")

Comment: ahh well that's good to know, thanks for that feedback -- I've got to get it working in I.E. 8 as well, but glad to hear the future is brighter :)

Comment: Just a thought.  The Validation plugin v1.9 is only up to date for jQuery 1.6.  Perhaps you should try jQuery 1.6.4 just to see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you give the `<option>` tags explicit "value" attributes, it works.

```
<option value='---'>---</option>
```

It's not clear to me why it fails in IE7 but not IE8.

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be a validator bug. But as a work around, you may consider select the element and get the value. See this, working on IE7:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || $(element).val() !== param;
}, "Please choose some value!");
```

Comment: nice, I'd found element.item(element.selectedIndex).text != param;
but your solution is much cleaner -- I'm relatively new to using jQuery -- I tried using element.val() but that didn't work, didn't realize I needed to use $(element) to get the jquery'ized version, but that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

It's because none of your options have values.

```
    <option value='---'>---</option>
    <option value='Category 1'>Category 1</option>
    <option value='Category 2'>Category 2</option>
    <option value='Category 3'>Category 3</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the word "text" for your `id` and `name`.

The word "text" is not specifically *"reserved"* but it's one of those *"words best to avoid"*...

http://www.kourbatov.com/faq/reserved.htm

---

Also, the [Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) has only been tested up to jQuery version 1.6.1

Downgrade your jQuery version just to rule out an issue with jQuery 1.7

Comment: thanks for the tip -- I would certainly never use the word text in regular code, or generally even in a test example -- this one started out by forking someone elses jsfiddle :) -- I tried with earlier versions of jQuery btw, and they're a problem also -- looks like I.E. handles the option value thing a bit differently than other browsers (pre IE 9 anyway)

Answer (score 0):

guess this should work

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.validate-1.9.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm').validate({
      rules: {
          text: {
              required: true
          },
          category: {
              required: true
          }
      },
      messages: {
          text: {
              required: "Text required"
          },
          category: {
              required: "Category required"
          }
      }
  });
});
    </script>
<form id="myForm">
    <select id="category" name="category">
        <option value="">---</option>
        <option value="Category 1">Category 1</option>
        <option value="Category 2">Category 2</option>
        <option value="Category 3">Category 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="text" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Test" />
</form
</body>
</html>
```